# C# HashSet root algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, hashset

I came across Hashing algorithm and wondering what algorithm is used in C# HashSet library?
Is there a place to find it out or someone actually documented this?
Hope someone here can help out!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,2d265edc718b158b